# How can I reset the password of Jenkins?

Tags: security, jenkins

I just noticed I cannot login in my Jenkins.

How can I reset my password and access to my account again? I do not see any link to recover passwords and they seem to be hashed in the installation directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [How to reset password of Jenkins](http://it.i88.ca/2013/04/reset-password-of-jenkins.html) you have a set of tricks to make this happen. I based my solution on it, but it diverges in a certain point.

This is what I did to solve the issue:

Let's assume Jenkins' directory is stored in `$JENKINS` (in my machine this is `/var/lib/jenkins/`) and your username is `user`.

- **Allow signups** by disabling `disableSignup`. This means editing `$JENKINS/config.xml` and setting this option to `false`:

  ```
  <disableSignup>false</disableSignup>
  ```
- **Restart Jenkins** (`service jenkins restart`).
- Enter in Jenkins and **register a new user**, for example `testuser`, with the password being the one you want to set to your user `user`.
- **Extract the hashed password** from `$JENKINS/users/testuser/config.xml`. You will see something like:

  ```
  <passwordHash>#jbcrypt:$2a$10$PY7p4dxFiGSgJpxiNVTQDuJKAQ8pr9snDgQXaafogjErvgB0oC3qy</passwordHash>
  ```
- **Set the `user`'s password** to this one in `<passwordHash>`. That is, edit `$JENKINS/users/user/config.xml` and replace the password there to set the one above.
- **Disallow signups back** by enabling `disableSignup`. That is, in `$JENKINS/config.xml` set the `disableSignup` option back to `true`:

  ```
  <disableSignup>true</disableSignup>
  ```
- **Restart Jenkins** again.

Note you can also replace the password directly by generating a jBCrypt. For example, in http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/ you can find some Java code for it.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach for Windows that solved this issue for me:

In
`C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\config.xml`, change `useSecurity` to false.

[image]

The restart Jenkins, you will now get full access without login. Go to **People**, select the old admin user and delete the user.

Then set

```
<disableSignup>false</disableSignup>
```

and

```
<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
```

Restart Jenkins again, and you will now be able to register again.

Finally

```
<disableSignup>true</disableSignup>
```